# Elastic search not returning result

Tags: elasticsearch

I am very new to elastic search and I am using high level rest clint to get result from ES. The query that is forming is:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(a^10 OR a*^5)",
      "fields": [
        "SearchName^1.0",
        "SearchName.folded^1.0"
      ],
      "type": "best_fields",
      "default_operator": "or",
      "max_determinized_states": 10000,
      "enable_position_increments": true,
      "fuzziness": "AUTO",
      "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
      "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
      "phrase_slop": 0,
      "escape": false,
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
      "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Source": {
              "value": "TALENT2",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "LastModifiedTs": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Above query is working fine if i remove post filter condition but is giving no result with post filter.

Comment: Does your `Source` column contain a value of `Talent2`?

Comment: Yes it does contain.